# Why paragraph is not stretching to the full body in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am facing a pecurliar problem in MS Office. I am using MS Office 2010 Professional Version.

Text in word does not fully cover the whole body space in a page. You can see in the attached image, margin is actually up to the Red line at right. But every line is wrapping actually up to the Green line. As for example, You may see that even there are enough space after **"...time as you"** at first line of third paragraph to bring the **"need"** word from second line, but this is not happening.

Paragraph is Left Align with Body Text Outline Level. Indentation of Left and Right is 0cm, Spacing is 0pt and Line spacing is Single for Paragraph Setting of the page.

[image]

Could someone help me in resolving this issue so that the paragraph text fit inside the actual margin?

Comment: Is there a line break at the end of those lines (inserted by pressing `Shift`+`Enter`)? It would be helpful to see two more screenshots: formatting symbols within those paragraphs and the formatting details pane. To reveal the hidden formatting symbols press the "Show\Hide" button (looks like the Greek letter Pi). To show the formatting pane click `Shift`+`F1` when the cursor placed is inside the text.

Comment: It would be helpful to post an example document.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how later this problem was resolved automatically or perhaps by pressing any combination of keys. That's why the problem was not able to reproduce. Thank You all for all of your suggestions. If found in the future, I obviously will show you the screenshot.
Thanks